# MongoDBException: Invalid find by call

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, php-5.6

I have a MongoDBException:

> "Invalid find by call Bundle\Document\Property::$fieldName
>   (criteriaWith)".

I don't understand what is wrong here. Can someone help me please?

Here's the **Stack Trace**:

1 . in `vendor/doctrine/mongodb-odm/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/MongoDBException.php` at line 38

```
public static function invalidFindByCall($documentName, $fieldName, $method) {
    return new self(sprintf('Invalid find by call %s::$fieldName (%s)', $documentName, $fieldName, $method));
}
```

2. at

> MongoDBException ::invalidFindByCall ('\Bundle\Document\Property',
>   'criteriaWith', 'findByCriteriaWith')

in `vendor/doctrine/mongodb-odm/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/DocumentRepository.php` at line 222

```
if ($this->class->hasField($fieldName)) {
    return $this->$method(array($fieldName => $arguments[0]));
} else {
    throw MongoDBException::invalidFindByCall($this->documentName, $fieldName, $method . $by);
}
```

3. at `DocumentRepository ->__call ('findByCriteriaWith', array(array('name' => 'ho')))` in `src/Bundle/Controller/PropertyController.php` at line 286

   ```
   else {
        criteria['name'] = $name;
        $entities = $repository->findByCriteriaWith($criteria);
   }
   ```

**The Log Messages:**

> CRITICAL  request     Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\MongoDBException: "Invalid find by call
>   Bundle\Document\Property::$fieldName (criteriaWith)" at
>   vendor/doctrine/mongodb-odm/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/MongoDBException.php
>   line 38 Context: { "exception":
>   "Object(Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\MongoDBException)" }

Comment: looks like your DocumentRepository.php class does not have a field called 'criteriaWith' which seems to be must

Answer (score 0):

Let's go through ODM's document repository [magic `__call` method](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/blob/6f49353c16ca6bed3dc1d27882a2ab54696e7839/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/DocumentRepository.php#L210) (as that's what is called since `findByCriteriaWith` does not exist) and highlight interesting parts.

First we see

```
 if (strpos($method, 'findBy') === 0) {
     $by = substr($method, 6, strlen($method));
     $method = 'findBy';
 }
```

Your method name starts with "findBy" so we will enter this block leaving us later with `$method = 'findBy'` and `$by = 'CriteriaWith'` Later on `$by` gets camelized, as that's standard for field/property name, and leaves us with `$fieldName = 'criteriaWith'`. Now next thing we see is `$this->class->hasField($fieldName)` check which results in exception you got because your class does not have a `criteriaWith` field.

Summing up `$repository->findBySomething($value);` is equivalent to `$repository->findBy(['something' => $value])` and throws exception if field does not exist in your doocument.